# Eclipse crashes on Android SDK and AVD Manager

Tags: android, eclipse

I tried to install Android SDK plugin on my existing Eclipse Classic 3.6.0 (Helios). I managed to do everything else, but when I try to add components using Android SDK and AVD Manager in Eclipse, whole Eclipse just crashes.

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

[Eclipse Crash Log on pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/x3fdLSQa)

Comment: I think this is an eclipse/java problem, not android. Try using 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: there is NO date shown on this page( Currently 2010 Nov )
This page states,

http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html

System Requirements

Supported Development Environments
Eclipse IDE

Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede) or 3.5 (Galileo)

Caution: There are known issues with the ADT plugin running with Eclipse 3.6. Please stay on 3.5 until further notice.

ALSO NOTE
looking at your pastebin.com post
you PATH variable is corrupt

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 2013, using Android Dev Tools (Android SDK and Eclipse), build v21.0.1 - the AVD Manager crashed repeatedly using JDK v7x. Using JDK v6x resolved the issue, able to setup virtual devices now.

Comment: Im having a similar problem. Can you please tell me exactly how to set the AVD Manager to use JDK6 instead of JDK7, if I have both installed already?